# Access POST form data and write it in an xml file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, post

So I've been looking for a good solution everywhere but did not find anything useful. So basically what I want to do is to access the (post) form data with C# in the codebehind of an .aspx web form and then write that data into a xml (and also create the xml of course).

Let us say I have something like this:

```
<asp:Content runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="pageContent">

    <form id="form1" method="post" name="contact" action="contact.aspx">
       (...)
       <input type="button" value="Send" id="submit"
    </form>

</asp:Content>
```

now I guess it doesn't matter what's inside the form.

I found this xml writer class --> http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.xml.xmlwriter(v=VS.80).aspx, but I really just don't know where to start.

If anybody can help me with that or maybe this question has been answered here before and I just overlooked it, so you could link me there I'd be grateful for that.

thanks in advance!

Comment: Which part is giving you problems - getting the data, or creating the XML? They're entirely separate aspects, and you should ask a question on one or the other of them, or two separate questions.

Comment: well actually I have problems with the whole process, so bboth of them. Well I thought as these two processes are connected to each other I ask them in one question...

Comment: But they're not *intrinsically* connected. A large part of programming is splitting a big task into smaller ones. The two initial smaller ones here are extracting the data from a form, and writing "some data" (wherever it's come from) to an XML document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use the `<form>` tag in ASP.NET WebForms because there's already a `<form runat="server">` and HTML forms cannot be nested. So here you have 2 different tasks to accomplish:

1. Send POST data to Contact.aspx
2. Use the POST data in Contact.aspx to generate a XML file

So let's tackle those two separate tasks starting with the first one. Let's suppose that you have a Default.aspx web form in which the user will enter some input data:

```
<div>
    First name: <asp:TextBox ID="EdtFirstName" runat="server" />
</div>
<div>
    Last name: <asp:TextBox ID="EdtLastName" runat="server" />
</div>

<asp:LinkButton ID="BtnSubmit" runat="server" PostBackUrl="Contact.aspx" Text="Generate XML" />
```

and in the code behind you would expose the 2 values:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return EdtFirstName.Text; }
    }

    public string LastName
    {
        get { return EdtLastName.Text; }
    }
}
```

Now we could move on to implementing the second task of generating the XML file inside `Contact.aspx`:

```
public partial class Contact : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var page = (Page.PreviousPage as _Default);
        if (page != null)
        {
            var xml = new XDocument(
                new XElement(
                    "user",
                    new XElement("firstName", page.FirstName),
                    new XElement("lastName", page.LastName)
                )    
            );
            var file = Server.MapPath("~/test.xml");
            xml.Save(file);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, I'll try this out. This could also be done in one file? If I have my form in the contact.aspx I would just still set the  PostBackUrl to Contact.aspx and then to both things in the same codebehind?

Comment: Yes, it can be done in one file. In this case it is even easier. You don't need to use the `PostBackUrl` property at all and you don't need to publicly expose the FirstName and LastName properties because you already have access to them. In this case simply subscribe to the `OnClick` event of the LinkButton and perform the XML generation part there.

Comment: so would it be something like this then?:


`var xml = new XDocument(
                new XElement(
                    "user",
                    new XElement("firstName", EdtFirstName.Text,(...)`

What would the `OnClick` events value be?
Sorry I'm new to all this :)

Comment: Yes, you could directly use `EdtLastName.Text`. And then `OnClick="BtnGenerateXMLClick"`. And finally you will declare the callback in your code behind where you will generate the XML file: `protected void BtnGenerateXMLClick(object sender, EventArgs e) { ... }`. Finally you should go through the ASP.NET getting started tutorials here: http://www.asp.net/web-forms to learn at least some basic concepts.

Comment: allright, thanks a lot! I guess I'll have to read through that :)

Comment: Yes, you will have to read. Without reading it is very unlikely to learn a new technology.